# How to convince the tokenizer to work correctly with single sentence

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have the following sentence (only one), When I use the following code for tokenizing and knowing the index of each word, the tokenizer considers it like two sentences due to the full-stop after "approx". How can I solve this problem:

```
String sentence = "09-Aug-2003 -- On Saturday, 9th August 2003, Daniel and I start with our Enduros approx. 100 kilometers from the confluence point."

Annotation document = new Annotation(sentence);
pipeline.annotate(document);
for (CoreLabel token : document.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class)) {
     String word = token.get(CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation.class);
     System.out.println(token.index(), word);
}
```

e.g. the true index of "kilometers" is 20. But according to this code is 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the following to the Properties object that you pass in to `pipeline`

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit");
props.setProperty("ssplit.isOneSentence", "true");

StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

then it won't split the text into different sentences.

(search 'ssplit' on this page to see all the other options http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml)